Why doesn't my input clear when pressing "Enter" using a custom useKey hook in React?
I am trying to create a search input component in React where the search query should reset to an empty string when the "Enter" key is pressed, unless the input is currently focused.
I am using a custom useKey hook to listen for key events globally, but the input doesn't reset as expected when I press "Enter". Here's my setup:
Custom Hook: useKey
This hook listens for specific key presses and triggers a callback:
import { useEffect } from "react";

export function useKey(key, action) {
  useEffect(() => {
    function callback(e) {
      if (e.code.toLowerCase() === key.toLowerCase()) {
        action();
      }
    }

    document.addEventListener("keydown", callback);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("keydown", callback);
    };
  }, [key, action]);
}


Search Component
This is my Search component, which uses the useKey hook to reset the query state and focus on the input:
import { useRef } from "react";
import { useKey } from "./useKey";

export default function Search({ query, setQuery }) {
  const inputEl = useRef(null);

  useKey("Enter", function () {
    if (document.activeElement === inputEl.current) {
      // If the input is focused, do nothing
      return;
    }

    // Reset the query and focus on the input
    inputEl.current.focus();
    setQuery(""); 
  });

  return (
    <input
      type="text"
      placeholder="Search"
      value={query}
      onChange={(e) => setQuery(e.target.value)}
      ref={inputEl}
    />
  );
}

Parent Component
Here is my parent component, which manages the query state:
import { useState } from "react";
import Search from "./Search";

export default function App() {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("");

  return (
    <div>
      <Search query={query} setQuery={setQuery} />
      <p>Current search: {query}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

Problem:
When I type something in the input (e.g., "hello") and press "Enter", I expect the query state to reset to an empty string (""), and the displayed search query to update to "Current search: ". However, the query state doesn't reset, and the input still shows the same text.
Here’s what I’ve tried so far:

Verified that the setQuery function is being called by adding logs,
and it is called with an empty string ("").

Checked that the useKey hook is firing the callback when the "Enter" key is pressed,and it is.

Ensured no other listeners or components are interfering.


Despite this, the input value doesn’t reset as expected.
What I Expect:

The query state should reset to "" when "Enter" is pressed.
The input field should clear, and the "Current search" text should
reflect the empty state.

Additional Notes:

I'm using React 18.3.1

The useKey hook is used in other components as well, but I don't
think they interfere with this one.


Question:
What could be causing the query state to not reset as expected, and how can I fix this issue?

Well asked question - but given your code, I'm not able to reproduce your issue. Are you able to maybe create a runnable snippet to showcases it?

When I type something in the input (e.g., "hello") and press "Enter", I expect the query state to reset to an empty string ("") - you are blurring/unfocusing the input as well right before you hit "Enter"?

I suggest not using addEventListeners. You could make an attribute onKeyDown and pass in your hook, or if you want to abstract it, a function that calls the hook with "Enter" and the function you pass in. This way, you don't need to worry about refs and event listeners. In fact, you don't even really need that hook anymore, and useEffects are bad for performance.

@NickParsons I have created a react project on Sandbox here is the link : https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/dkgsh5

@Pixtane Thank you for your suggestion! I’m using the useKey hook because I need to handle key events globally, not just within specific components. This hook already works perfectly in another component where the "Escape" key is used to close a modal. However, with the "Enter" key in this case, it doesn’t clear the input as expected when setQuery("") is called, and I’m not sure why.
If you have ideas on improving this while keeping it reusable and modular, I’d love to hear them!

@Lazare The sandbox doesn't seem to reproduce the issue either? I type in "hello", click off of the input text box to blur it, and then hit enter and it clears it.

@NickParsons Hi, the project should now be accessible. I had forgotten to set it to public—sorry about that! You can check it again using the same link. Let me know if you encounter any issues.

@Lazare Thanks, access it working now. But it doesn't seem to reproduce the issue, if I type "Hello", click off the text box (so it's no longer selected), and hit "Enter" the text gets cleared.

@NickParsons Actually, it’s working now! It’s strange because when I was testing earlier, nothing seemed to work. But now, it clears the text when I click off the text box and hit "Enter." Thanks for your patience!
